# Crear array con el value de radio button y checkbox

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy realizando un odontodiagrama (diagrama que utilizan los dentistas para marcar los trabajos en los dientes para ello dispongo de un grupo de botones radio buton para representar los trabajos a realizar (controles) y cada diente los represento con un checkbox

```css
.arriba{
 width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-right: 15px solid transparent;
border-left: 15px solid transparent;
border-top: 15px solid #45494d80;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
margin-left: 20px;
transform: rotate(3deg);
cursor: pointer;
margin-bottom: 52px;
  }

 .izquierda{
  width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-right: 15px solid transparent;
border-left: 15px solid transparent;
border-top: 15px solid #d9d3dd;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
transform: rotate(275deg);
margin-top: -60px;
margin-left: 12px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
  } 

  .abajo{
 width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-right: 15px solid transparent;
border-left: 15px solid transparent;
border-top: 15px solid #45494d80;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
margin-left: 19px;
transform: rotate(184deg);
margin-top: -13px;
cursor: pointer;
  }

  .derecha{
 width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-right: 15px solid transparent;
border-left: 15px solid transparent;
border-top: 15px solid #d9d3dd;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
transform: rotate(454deg);
margin-top: -21px;
margin-left: 26px;
cursor: pointer;
  } 

  .centro{
   width: 15px;
height: 15PX;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
background: #d9d3dd;
border: 1px solid #555; 
position: absolute;
margin-left: 27px;
margin-top: -16px;
cursor: pointer;  
  }
```

```html
<p>
controles
</p>
 <label id="operatoria" class="check btn btn-default">
<input  type="radio" name="" id="operatoria" value="operatoria" autocomplete="off">Operatorias </label>

<label id="operatoria" class="check btn btn-default">
<input  type="radio" name="" id="caries" value="caries" autocomplete="off">Caries </label>

<label id="operatoria" class="check btn btn-default">
<input  type="radio" name="" id="exodoncia" value="exodoncia" autocomplete="off">exodoncia </label>




<div data-name="value" id="dienteindex" class="diente col-md-2" style="width:12%; margin-bottom:20px;">
                <span style="margin-left: 23px; margin-bottom:5px; display: inline-block !important; border-radius: 10px !important;" class="label label-info"> 16</span>
                <div id="t16" class="arriba cuadro click" value="arr">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="t16" hidden="" value="t16"></div>
                <div id="l16" class="cuadro izquierda click" value="izq">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="l16" hidden="" value="l16"></div>
                <div id="b16" class="cuadro abajo click" value="aba">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="b16" hidden="" value="b16"></div>
                <div id="r16" class="cuadro derecha click click" value="der">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="r16" hidden="" value="r16"></div>
                <div id="c16" class="centro centros click" value="cen">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="c16" hidden="" value="c16"></div>
                </div>
                
                
<div data-name="value" id="dienteindex" class="diente col-md-2" style="width:12%; margin-bottom:20px;">
                <span style="margin-left: 23px; margin-bottom:5px; display: inline-block !important; border-radius: 10px !important;" class="label label-info"> 17</span>
                <div id="t17" class="arriba cuadro click" value="arr">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="t17" hidden="" value="t17"></div>
                <div id="l17" class="cuadro izquierda click" value="izq">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="l17" hidden="" value="l17"></div>
                <div id="b17" class="cuadro abajo click" value="aba">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="b17" hidden="" value="b17"></div>
                <div id="r17" class="cuadro derecha click click" value="der">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="r17" hidden="" value="r17"></div>
                <div id="c17" class="centro centros click" value="cen">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="c17" hidden="" value="c17"></div>
                </div>
                
<div data-name="value" id="dienteindex" class="diente col-md-2" style="width:12%; margin-bottom:20px;">
                <span style="margin-left: 23px; margin-bottom:5px; display: inline-block !important; border-radius: 10px !important;" class="label label-info"> 18</span>
                <div id="t18" class="arriba cuadro click" value="arr">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="t18" hidden="" value="t18"></div>
                <div id="l18" class="cuadro izquierda click" value="izq">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="l18" hidden="" value="l18"></div>
                <div id="b18" class="cuadro abajo click" value="aba">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="b18" hidden="" value="b18"></div>
                <div id="r18" class="cuadro derecha click click" value="der">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="r18" hidden="" value="r18"></div>
                <div id="c18" class="centro centros click" value="cen">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" name="check[]" id="c18" hidden="" value="c18"></div>
                </div>
```

nesesito poder guardar los values de ambos en un solo array para luego poder mostrarlo en un historial tal cual como lo marco hasta ahora solo puedo capturar todos las posiciones de los dientes usando php

```
 if (is_array($_POST['check'])) {
    $selected = '';
    $position = count($_POST['check']);
    $current = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['check'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($current != $position-1)
            $selected .= $value.', ';
        else
            $selected .= $value.'.';
        $current++;
    }
}
else {
    $selected = 'Debes seleccionar un diente';
}

echo '<div>Has seleccionado: '.$selected.'</div>';

$odont = $this->input->post('check[]');
    $ctr = $this->input->post('odonto');
    if ($odont != NULL) {

        $odont = str_replace(',', ' ', $odont);                

    }
```

este php me trae como resultado lo siguiente
Array ( [0] => t18 [1] => r18 [2] => c17 [3] => l16 [4] => c15 )

ahora lo que nesesito es poder ingresar en ese mismo array si es posible los valores de los controles de modo que quedaria asi

Array ( [0] => operatoria [1] => r18 [2] => c17 [3] => caries [4] => c15 )

de antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme para resolver este problema que tengo